# Changing code style in WebStorm 9.0.2

Tags: webstorm

I am trying to [change my WebStorm settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/code-style-javascript.html) for a project such that JavaScript spacing is two spaces as opposed to four. I have changed the project settings from both Webstorm > Preferences > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript and Default Settings > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript, yet have seen no carryover into the actual project, which continues to use four spaces. The preview pane on this view appears exactly as I want.

In both aforementioned paths, I hit Apply once I made changes; I've also gone into the Scheme dropdown and selected my desired settings.

I have also restarted my WebStorm, verified my settings were changed, but still am not seeing any effect take place in the project.

Answer (score 3):

The culprit here for me was a .editorconfig file where someone had previously specified `indent_size`. This file will override the default WebStorm settings. As it's a hidden file, easy to miss so be on the lookout! :-)